# Matching a Pattern in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to validate whether or not a string contains and starts with `BA700`. I have tried using the `preg_match()` function in PHP but I have not had any luck. My code is below:

`preg_match('/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$/', $search))`

This does not work unfortunately. Any ideas?

UPDATES CODE:

```
$needle = 'BA700';
$haystack = 'BA70012345';

if (stripos($haystack, $needle)) {
    echo 'Found!';
}
```

This does not work for me either

Comment: Are you looking for exactly BA700?

Comment: @DanielWilliams I am looking for the string to contain BA700. But it will most like have other numbers/letters afterwards

Comment: @jeff I just updated my code using the stripos function. It does not seem to work.

Comment: ho hum. stripos returns the position within the string - in this case it is zero which happens the be the value for false. Therefore you need to code: if( stripos($haystack, $needle) !== false ) { .... }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to correctly use stripos

```
if (stripos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
    echo 'Found!';
}
```

Comment: This does not make sure that the string **begins** with BA700. It just makes sure that it appears somewhere in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `substr` like

```
$needle = 'BA700';
$haystack = 'BA70012345';
if(substr($haystack, 0, 4) == $needle) {
    echo "Valid";
} else {
    echo "In Valid";
}
```

You can also check regards with the case by changing both of them in either `UPPER` or `LOWER` like

```
if(strtoupper(substr($haystack, 0, 4)) == $needle) {
    echo "Valid";
} else {
    echo "In Valid";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am taking this a little too literally, but:

```
if (strncmp($string, 'BA700', 5) === 0) {
    // Contains and begins with 'BA700'
}
```

If the `BA700` is case-insensitive then:

```
if (strncasecmp($string, 'ba700', 5) === 0) {
    // Contains and begins with 'ba700'
}
```

There should not be much more to it than that.

The regular expression, in case you want to know, is:

```
if (preg_match('/^BA700/', $string) === 1) {
    // Contains and begins with 'ba700'
}
```